# Mantain wagtail category across pages

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

I've a pagination system on my Wagtail website that works just fine with normal posts. However, I wanted to make pagination of post categories and I wasn't able to do it, it loads the "Posts" URL losing the category.

You can see an example here when clicking page 2
https://wizardeo.es/publicaciones/?category=guias

This is the code of my template

```html
                {% if posts.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
                    {% if not 1 == posts.number and posts.number >= 4 %}
                        {% if posts.paginator.num_pages > 5  %}
                            <a href="?page=1">&lt;&lt;</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    
                    {% for page_num in posts.paginator.page_range %}

                        {% if posts.number == 1 %}
                            {% if page_num > posts.number|add:-3  and page_num < posts.number|add:5 %}
                                <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="{% if page_num == posts.number %} active {% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>    
                            {% endif %}
                        {% elif posts.number == 2 %}      
                            {% if page_num > posts.number|add:-2  and page_num < posts.number|add:4 %}
                                <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="{% if page_num == posts.number %} active {% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>    
                            {% endif %}
                        {% elif posts.number == 3 %}                            
                            {% if page_num > posts.number|add:-3  and page_num < posts.number|add:3 %}
                                <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="{% if page_num == posts.number %} active {% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>    
                            {% endif %}
                        {% elif posts.paginator.num_pages == posts.number %} 
                            {% if page_num > posts.number|add:-5  and page_num < posts.number|add:3 %}
                                <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="{% if page_num == posts.number %} active {% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>    
                            {% endif %}
                        {% elif posts.number == posts.paginator.num_pages|add:-1 %} 
                            {% if page_num > posts.number|add:-4  and page_num < posts.number|add:2 %}
                                <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="{% if page_num == posts.number %} active {% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>    
                            {% endif %}   
                        {% elif posts.number == posts.paginator.num_pages|add:-2 %} 
                            {% if page_num > posts.number|add:-3  and page_num < posts.number|add:3 %}
                                <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="{% if page_num == posts.number %} active {% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>    
                            {% endif %}                                               
                        {% else %}
                            {% if page_num > posts.number|add:-3  and page_num < posts.number|add:3 %}
                                <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="{% if page_num == posts.number %} active {% endif %}">{{ page_num }}</a>    
                            {% endif %}     
                        {% endif %}  

                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if not posts.paginator.num_pages == posts.number and posts.number <= posts.paginator.num_pages|add:-3 %}
                        {% if posts.paginator.num_pages > 5  %}
                            <a href="?page={{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}">&gt;&gt;</a>
                        {% endif %}                    
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
```

This is my models.py

```py
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if request.GET.get('category'):

            category_posts = BlogDetailPage.objects.live().public().filter(categories__slug__in=[request.GET.get('category')]).order_by('-first_published_at')
            paginator = Paginator(category_posts, 6)
            page = request.GET.get("page")
            try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

            context["posts"] = posts

        else:
            all_posts = BlogDetailPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
            paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 6)
            page = request.GET.get("page")
            try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

            context["posts"] = posts
        return context
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your template code is not passing your filter parameters and that is why you are losing your category. Have a look at this blog post and adapt it to your needs: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/10/18/filtering-and-pagination-django/#combining-filtering-and-pagination